# Full center pictures with different formats in fixed width/height divs

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a slider with 220px x 220px squared divs. Each div contain one picture and I want it to fit the div. I have pictures in landscape format and others in portrait format.
You can check an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/m7ntythy/
Here's the code :

```
<div>
    <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/landscape-photography-1.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.sallyportraits.com/assets/images/pencil_portraits_-cm05.jpg" />
</div>

div
{
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

$('img').each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > $(this).width())
    {
        $(this).css('width', '100%');
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    }
    if ($(this).height() < $(this).width())
    {
        $(this).css('width', 'auto');
        $(this).css('height', '100%');
    }
});
```

The problem is, sometimes, if the javascript does not load correctly, the pictures are displayed in full size.
I want to know if there's a CSS rollback which at least displays the pictures correctly or a way to force the javascript pictures resizing?

Comment: Do you need the whole picture visible on the thumbnail or will it still work with only part of the image visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just drop the javascript and replace it with pure css. By the way I think the crop you have with your current solution is propably not what you want, because the landscape image is not cropped centered.

If you don't mind having the image as a div background, this is my solution for this problem:

```
<div class="tile image-crop" style="background-image: url('http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/landscape-photography-1.jpg');"></div>
<div class="tile image-crop" style="background-image: url('http://www.sallyportraits.com/assets/images/pencil_portraits_-cm05.jpg');"></div>

.tile {
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.image-crop {
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Working Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmrPK)

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the inline background image style that's why I choose this answer instead of Xiao Yanhao's one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use background-image to solve this problem.

```
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='b'></div>

div
{
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.a
{
    background-image: url("http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/landscape-photography-1.jpg");
}

.b
{
    background-image: url("http://www.sallyportraits.com/assets/images/pencil_portraits_-cm05.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Good solution. I don't choose this one just because I have a lot of pictures and it's tedious to add multiples css classes just to specify background images.